# Laravel table migration in cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

Hlw everyone. I had added a laravel project in cpanel and now i want to customize it and made some changes. In local i use artisan command to migrate my changes to but how to do it in cpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s better to have a **vps** while using laravel projects.

Or you should have a **SSH access** to do it.

Some hosting companies will give you SSH access on cPanel or directadmin hosts.

**What is SSH** ? in a simple word it is a terminal on your host or server which you can run commands like *php artisan migrate* remotely

Comment: I've been searching all the internet and some blog says i may or may not be able to migrate from ssh command. Can we use terminal that is given in my cpanel?

Comment: There is no problem with migrating using SSH access. Of course you can use terminal given in cPanel. If you had any problem to run the command and migrate let me know to help